# ValueError: shapes (2,) and (10,10) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 10 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression

I keep on getting this error

> **ValueError:** shapes (2,) and (10,10) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 10 (dim
>   0)

I have tried converting the inputs to matrices and switched around some of the values in the matmul

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def ridge_regression_weights(input_x, output_y, lambda_param):

    lambda_p_value = lambda_param
    X = input_x
    X = np.squeeze(np.asarray(X))
    y = output_y
    y = np.squeeze(np.asarray(y))
    trans_x = np.transpose(X)
    XTX = np.matmul(trans_x, X)
    Left = np.linalg.inv(lambda_p_value + XTX)
    Right = np.matmul(output_y, trans_x)
    RidgeRegression = np.matmul(Right, Left)
    print(RidgeRegression)
```

There should not be any error

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When you are receiving an error, it is very helpful if you provide the full traceback of the error for troubleshooting purposes. Additionally, a sample input and output would help make a [mcve] for your issue

Comment: Which matmul?  Print some shapes.  Did you expect either shape in the error.  Don't guess shapes.  Test. Check dtype also.